# Save "perf stat" output to a file without also saving the executed command's output

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, perf

I'm running `perf stat` on the command `./start-server.sh -f server-config.xml`:

`perf stat -e cache-misses ./start-server.sh -f server-config.xml`

I'd like to save the `perf` results to a file e.g. by appending `&>out.txt` to the command, however if I write the output to a file then I capture both the `perf` output as well as the `start-server` output.  Is there a way for me to execute this command such that only the `perf` output will be written to the output file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From `perf help stat` on my Debian 7:

> `-o file`, `--output file`
>              Print the output into the designated file.

Try:

```
perf stat -o out.txt -e cache-misses ./start-server.sh -f server-config.xml
```